# PHP "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'"

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have a problem with PHP and, although I spent a whole hour trying to find what's wrong, I can't find anything in the code.

I'm working with a MySQL database and an input form. The form should be used to add entries to a specific table in the database. However, it gives a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'" whenever I hit the "Submit" button.

I tried everything but nothing worked.

This is the code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header("Location: index.html");
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit']=="Invia")){
    if(isset($_POST['section'])){
        $section = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['section'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        echo "Devi selezionare una sezione";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['offer'])){
        $offer = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['offer'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['title'])){
        $title = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        echo "Devi impostare il nome del viaggio";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['datestart'])){
        $datestart = date('Ymd', strtotime($_POST['datestart']));
    } else {
        echo "Devi selezionare una data di inizio";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['dateend'])){
        $dateend = date('Ymd', strtotime($_POST['dateend']));
    } else {
        echo "Devi selezionare una data di fine";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['itinerary'])){
        $itinerary = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['itinerary'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        echo "Devi inserire un itinerario";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['price'])){
        $price = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        echo "Devi inserire un prezzo";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['includes'])){
        $includes = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['includes'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        echo "Devi inserire La quota comprende!";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['pdfname'])){
        $pdfname = addslashes(filter_var($_POST['pdfname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        echo "Devi inserire un nome per il pdf";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['section']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['datestart']) && isset($_POST['dateend']) && isset($_POST['itinerary']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['includes']) && isset($_POST['pdfname'])){
    $data = new MysqlClass();
    $data->connetti();
     
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $section . " (
    `id` ,
    `title` ,
    `offer` ,
    `datestart` ,
    `dateend` ,
    `itinerary` ,
    `price` ,
    `includes` ,
    `pdfname`) 

    VALUES (
    NULL,
    '".$title."',
    '".$offer."',
    '".$datestart."',
    '".$dateend."',
    '".$itinerary."',
    '".$price."',
    '".$includes."',
    '".$pdfname."');";

    $data->query($query);
    echo "Viaggio inserito con successo.";
    $data->disconnetti();
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.html");
}
?>
```

EDIT: I'm using Wamp as a local server. I'm starting to think that's the problem, although it seems unlikely.

EDIT 2: I tried switching to EasyPHP, but I still have the same problem: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localweb\input.php on line 50

Comment: Check again, I had messed up the code while copying it here. Now it shows as it should (and there is no else on line 37).

Comment: so, check yourself by enabling errors at the top of your code. `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", "on");`

Comment: Just as a side note, if you're going to filter_var on an input, look at filter_input. Secondly, addslashes is not adequate protection when taking input and using it in a query. You should be using real_esacpe_string instead.

Comment: It could be due to the fact I'm using Wamp, but I keep seeing the same exact error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\input.php on line 52

Comment: Did you checked in MysqlClass file?

Comment: I did, no errors there. It works on other php pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['price'])){
    else { //<<---- missing } before else
        echo "Devi inserire un prezzo";
    }
```

There is also an "extra" closing bracket at the end of the script

Comment: I had messed up the code while copy-pasting it here on StackOverflow. Now it shows the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

when you use if statement you should do like this

```
if(){

}else{


}
```

and as  he told you above

```
if(isset($_POST['price'])){
    else { 
        echo "Devi inserire un prezzo";
    }
```

Thank You .

Comment: As I said above, the one yuo saw was not the actual code. I had messed it up while posting here. Please check the actual code! Thanks